# How to set a operator as a function in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use a recurssion formula as x(i+1) = x(i) +h 
How can I input that in the for loop but also find the y- values corresponding to this and allocate it into an array.  I tried

```
for i in range(n):
    i+1 = y(i) + h 
    dydx[i] = (y[i+1]+y[i-1]-y[i])/h**2
    dydx0 = [dydx[0]]
    print(dydx0)
```

This obviously gives me an error but I can't think of how to do this another way. Can someone help?

```
def f(x):
    return cos(pi*exp(-x))
    h = 0.01
    x = linspace(a,b,n+1)
    print(x)
    y = f(x)
    dydx = zeros(n+1)

for i in range(n):

    dydx[i] = (y[i+1]+y[i-1]-y[i])/h**2
    dydx0 = [dydx[0]]
    print(dydx0)
```

in the dydx formula when I evaluate dydx[i] = (y[i+1]+y[i-1]-y[i])/h**2 I want to do y(x+h)+ y(x-h)-y(x)/h but using i as x[i+1]=x[i] +h. so for example y[i+1] should be mean evaluate y at x[i+1] which itself depends on h..

Comment: Please fix the indentation and formatting

Comment: Part of the formatting has been fixed for you, but I still don't think this can be answered. Please see how to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the indentation is still incorrect.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? It is unclear what you want to do for the y-values.

Comment: in the dydx formula when I evaluate dydx[i] = (y[i+1]+y[i-1]-y[i])/h**2 I want to do y(x+h)+ y(x-h)-y(x)/h but using i as x[i+1]=x[i] +h. so for example y[i+1] should be mean evaluate y at x[i+1] which itself depends on h..

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question now @roganjosh

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question now. @Nivii1406

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're very new to Python! There's a couple of syntactical patterns that will help you as you go:

1. The **return** key will end a function, so none of your code below the **return** keyword in your function f() will work.
2. The left side of the equal sign should be the variable you want to assign/modify. In python this kind of line:

   i+1 = y(i) + h

   Reads as "add 1 to i" on the left and "add h to the result of the function y when given parameter i" on the right. It's all kinds of wrong.

If your goal is

> [using] the recursion formula as x(i+1) = x(i) +h How can I input that in the for loop but also find the y- values corresponding to this and allocate it into an array.

Your code would look more like this:

```
values_of_x = []
values_of_y = []
initial_x = 10
number_of_recursions = 100 


values_of_x.append(initial_x)
values_of_y.append(y(initial_x))


for i in range(number_of_recursions):
    current_x = values_of_x[-1]
    next_x = current_x + h
    next_y = y(next_x)
    values_of_x.append(next_x)
    values_of_y.append(next_y)

print('Values of x displayed below:')
print(values_of_x)
print('Values of y displayed below:')
print(values_of_y)
```

This assumes you have defined a function y() that takes in a value of x and gives you back a value, though judging from your example code you might be doing something a bit more complicated than that!